# in-app billing error unable to buy item error response 5 developer error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I am developing in-app purchase in my published app. 
I released Test APK in Alpha test.
Additionally I registered one managed item & two subscription items and activated.
When query to Google's servers, it does not returned any sku items and returned response 5 (Developer Error).

Has anybody a solution about this problem?

```
D/IabHelper(10309): Starting in-app billing setup.
D/IabHelper(10309): Billing service connected.
D/IabHelper(10309): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
D/IabHelper(10309): In-app billing version 3 supported for com.*********.******
D/IabHelper(10309): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
D/IabHelper(10309): Starting async operation: refresh inventory
D/IabHelper(10309): Querying owned items, item type: inapp
D/IabHelper(10309): Package name: com.*********.******
D/IabHelper(10309): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(10309): Owned items response: 0
D/IabHelper(10309): Continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(10309): Querying SKU details.
D/IabHelper(10309): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
D/IabHelper(10309): Querying owned items, item type: subs
D/IabHelper(10309): Package name: com.*********.******
D/IabHelper(10309): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(10309): Owned items response: 0
D/IabHelper(10309): Continuation token: null
D/IabHelper(10309): Querying SKU details.
D/IabHelper(10309): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
D/IabHelper(10309): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
D/IabHelper(10309): Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
D/IabHelper(10309): Constructing buy intent for , item type: subs
E/IabHelper(10309): In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 5:Developer Error
```

Comment: I think you have to add your account (the one you are signedin in your testing device) as test account, then only you can test in-app billing, also note that if you are testing with the same account that you have used for uploading your app on google account thn you can not use same account for testing, use another account as tester in google console to test in-app billing.

Comment: @Darshan Thank you for your comment. I always use test account for app testing. I don't understand this situation.

Comment: I cleared this problem. just miscode.. ㅡㅡ